# InnoScriptStudio2 error loading ISCmplr.dll

Tags: dll, windows-7, virtualbox

I just installed the lasted  inno script studio to generate installer for windows. The moment i run it, it prompts me with the error msh `error loading ISCmplr.dll` and the compiler cannnot run.

I installed in on a 32bit windows 7 machine, running on virtualbox.

Answer (score 32):

I got this error, although I had installed the latest version of both Inno Setup and Inno Script Studio.

The error message specifically states that the Compiler Directory might not be set correctly, and this was the case.

- Open Inno Script Studio and ignore the error
- Select Tool/Options from the menu
- Select "Compiler Settings" on the left hand side
- On the right hand side, browse for the compiler directory
- Store the modified options

In my case the compiler directory is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6**.

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had the same problem. Not sure but I think it was because I installed Inno Script Studio before Inno Setup, so when ISS searched for the compiler, didn't found it.
Following the steps did the trick! :D

Comment: This was the case for me, too.  I installed Inno Script Studio before Inno Setup.  This answer fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case, it worked. But compiler, by defauld, was located on 'C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Inno Setup 6" path.

Answer (score 6):

`ISCmplr.dll` is a compiler required by Inno Script Studio to compile scripts. It is maintained by Jordan Russell. Therefore, you will want to also download the compiler from Jordan's website, located here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php

Download the latest stable build and follow the instructions during the install dialog. When you are done, open Inno Script Studio. You will now be able to compile.

Comment: @perwyl-liu should have accepted this answer. this is the right answer. after installing Inno Setup, I had no problem opening and then compiling with Inno Script Studio without any other setup required because Inno Setup registers ISCmplr.dll and then Inno Script Studio is able to make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem recently. There are 2 ways to get Inno Script Studio. You can download it directly from kymoto (https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio/), or you can get it from jrsoftware in the Quick Start Pack (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php). If you get it from jrsoftware then it will automatically install the latest Inno Setup as well, but if you get it directly from kymoto it will not.

For me Inno Setup is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6. This is where the ISCmplr.dll is. If you do not have an Inno Setup folder then you need to go to jrsoftware and download it.

Assuming you are able to download and install it, you now need to tell Inno Script Studio where it is. Launch Inno Script Studio and go to Tools > Options. In the new window go to Compiler Settings and select the directory where the ISCmplr.dll is ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6" for me). It was initially blank for me regardless of where I got Inno Script Studio from.

Note: The Quick Start Pack from jrsoftware simply downloads the latest version of Inno Script Studio from kymoto.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me "_Launch Inno Script Studio and go to Tools > Options. In the new window go to Compiler Settings and select the directory where the ISCmplr.dll is ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6" for me)_". I got this issue issue becasue I had a previous version of InnoScript Studio already installed. I uninstalled it and installed the new version. It did not remove the settings so the new version of the tool retrieved the folder path of the compiler location from the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward 2019 I came looking for an answer. compiler directory is no longer in Program Files. Latest Inno Setup 6.0.3 you will find it in AppData. C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Inno Setup 6 and the ISCmplr.dll is there.

Inno Script Studio last updated April 2018

Comment: When I installed the "quick start" version I had to follow the same directions as Phil; the dll wasn't in my local app data folder as you described. Maybe it varies depending on the installer you use?

Comment: Yes it does. Tried the "quick start" and that puts it back in Progra Files. I install this silently so use the latest versions "innosetup-6.0.3.exe /SILENT /CURRENTUSER" and the Script Studio same way. I then add a reg file that adds location of ISCmplr.dll "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Kymoto Solutions\Inno Script Studio 2\Options\Compiler" so done deal and no errors

Answer (score 0):

first instal the program
there is a folder at first installation called => C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Script Studio
then start from quick start(it will populate the dlls in folder=> C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6 
then go to tools option compiler settings and point it to "AFTER you have STARTED the program FROM QuickStart => C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6